# Android app library efficencies

Tags: android, apk

Does Android do anything to share duplicated libraries across apps?  It seems that the OS could detect duplicate lib hashes and avoid having separate copies for each app.

If a user has 50 apps installed and many of them have versions of Android support, Kotlin, and Guava libs there would be a nice opportunity to save disk space.

Comment: you may also enable proguard as part of your build process to reduce your apk since it will removed unused methods and classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Android do anything to share duplicated libraries across apps?

No.

> It seems that the OS could detect duplicate lib hashes and avoid having separate copies for each app

Each app is digitally signed, so the decision of whether or not to include the libraries has to be done at build time. What you want would appear to require a time machine, to "retcon" Android to have this capability from the beginning. Alternatively, it would require distribution channel support to deliver different APK editions for different scenarios (e.g., newer devices get the APK sans libraries; older devices get the APK with libraries), and not all distribution channels will be in position to support that.

It is also unclear how this would work with respect to multidex and ProGuard. The shared library copies would need to be full libraries, not ones with items removed via ProGuard, since different apps would require different portions of the library. This might force all apps to use multidex, even where that would not ordinarily be required.

Security starts to become more of a problem. Where do the shared library copies come from? If you wish to limit it to a few "well known" libraries (e.g., Kotlin runtime), that's perhaps something that Google can manage. But a "first one in wins" approach raises the spectre of an app distributing a malicious copy of a library that winds up being shared.

Overall, your approach bears strong hallmarks to the "DLL hell" of the 1990s and the "JAR hell" of the 2000s. Shared libraries across apps are tricky to manage properly.

> If a user has 50 apps installed and many of them have versions of Android support, Kotlin, and Guava libs there would be a nice opportunity to save disk space.

Guava is not used much in Android development due to its size. With the notable exception of `appcompat-v7`, most of the Android support libraries are fairly small. I don't think that this will save as much disk space as one might think, and the cost of that savings winds up getting put on the backs of developers.